# delphi form constraint doesn't work when maximized

Tags: delphi

i try to maximize width and hold height. i use delphi xe4, windows 7, 1,440 * 900 2 monitors.

height constraint usually works well but when it exceeds certain value which is 859 it doesn't work.

i guessed that it was because of windows snap feature but even after the turning off that it's same.

when i do this in the sub monitor which doesn't have taskbar and in the main monitor with taskbar auto hide it works well. it seems the trouble with taskbar.

any help to solve this please. thanks.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Constraints.MaxHeight := 859; // works well

  WindowState := wsMaximized;

  Caption := IntToStr(Height);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Constraints.MaxHeight := 860; // doesn't work

  WindowState := wsMaximized;

  Caption := IntToStr(Height);  // maximized as 876
end;

procedure TForm1.FormConstrainedResize(Sender: TObject; var MinWidth, MinHeight, MaxWidth, MaxHeight: Integer);
begin
  MaxHeight := 860;             // doesn't works and is maximized as 876
end;
```

Comment: If you want to constrain the window's size, why are you maximising it?

Comment: What are the WorkArea dimansions? You can get this information from global screen variable with `Screen.WorkAreaRect` for instance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not to move with full width

Comment: That's not what maximising is about. I think you should describe the original problem rather than your attempted solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's the original problem. i need to make a full width * 860 charting window which should be used in all sizes of monitor.

Comment: So do that. Make the window have the same width as the monitor it is on, and constrain its height. I don't see how maximising can be relevant.

Comment: @SilverWarior WorkAreaHeight was 860. when a window is maximized top border shirnks and this makes the inner space of a form bigger. the problem has not been solved yet your comment helped what should i think about. thanks.

Comment: @David, I think it was FreeCell that would act similarly. Its height could vary, but not its width, so when it was maximized, it only took up a portion of the screen, anchored to the left edge. My impression was that that's just how the wm_GetMinMaxInfo message worked with maximized windows.

Comment: I'm glad if I perhaps lead you to thinking in the right way but I must admit that I'm still puzled of what are you trying to achieve. Are ypu perhaps trying to resize your window in a way that it is stretched across both monitors which are configured in side by side position and at the same time try limiting the heigh of your window so that it doesen't exceed the available height of smalest monitor.

Comment: Or are you interested in making something similar like Rob Kennedy just mentioned? Are you perhaps creating additional destkop taskbar or toolbar as it is officialy named?

Comment: Can't reproduce this in XE2 or XE7...

Comment: @SilverWarior rob is right. just the difference is that mine is anchored to the top. it's a charting form which is horizontally long and vertically short. band type streaming chart like stock charts.

Comment: @J... the form needs to approach near taskbar. maybe the height of your monitor resolution is bigger than mine.

Comment: @JOSeongGng Now I'm totally confused. If you need charting form which is horizontally long and vertically short why are you then even dealing with MaxHeight or maximizing of this form in the first place?

Comment: @SilverWarior i'm sorry that i can't understand your last comment. if i don't maximize the form it floats and isn't fixed in the screen which varys in many kinds of resolution. if i don't fix the height it occupies unnecessary room below the form especially in large monitors.

Comment: @JOSeongGng If you want your form to act as a toolbar then you need to tell the windows that. You do this by using ShAppBarMessage() winapi call. You can find example here http://www.delphipages.com/tip/application_desktop_toolbar__working___-10753.html There was also a component available for older Delphi versions. I think it was for Delphi 4 to 6. Best thing of using this approach is that Windows automatically reduces the workspace size so when other applications are maximized they will never cover your toolbar window nor will your toolbar window cover other applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to restrict the maximum size of the form when the user tries to maximise it then this will work.  I have my own Form class descended from `TForm` called `TRGNewForm` and all my forms descend from that.  However the scheme will work for the form you put the code in.

In the `Interface` section, in your Form class Public definition

```
  { Trap Sys Commands }
  procedure WMSysCommand (var Msg: TWMSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;
```

In the `Implementation`

```
procedure TRGNewForm.WMSysCommand (var Msg : TWMSysCommand);
begin
  { If MdiChild and Maximize button pressed, then use our own routine,
    as Windows has a bug }
  if (Msg.CmdType = SC_MAXIMIZE) and
     (FormStyle = fsMDIChild)
  then Maximise_Child_Form
  else DefaultHandler (Msg);
end;
```

In `Maximise_Child_Form` you set the height and width as required.

Comment: thanks. i'm sorry that i can't add a vote because of my poor reputation.

Comment: If you can tick it as the right answer then please do so.